# Can CDC read through a log file when the agent job hasn't been running?

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

We currently had CDC running on our SQL server, however, at some point last week the CDC capture job stopped running and started throwing an error. At this point when it stopped somebody had restored the database from a backup during a failed upgrade. I am interested to know if CDC will pick up where it left off when the underlying issues stopping the job from running is resolved, and read through the log file creating CDC entries for the time in between, or will it simply start the capture again?

Comment: Did you restore it on the same server with the same name? In that case, it will not read through logs and pick up changes but should start the capture again.

Comment: Yes, the restore was done over the top of the existing database with the same name, same server.